# How can i set variables in SQLCMD

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

```
SQLCMD 
-S <serverName> 
-U sa -P <password> 
-d <DatabaseBase>
-Q "select top(1) * from table order by 1 desc" 
-o "new.propertie"
```

When i am using the instead of  it is not working

Variable i created

```
:setvar servaername "ServerName"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue could be that variable names are case sensitive.  You have "serverName" and "ServerName", in your example.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx

> Variables
>   :Setvar  [ "value" ]
>   Defines sqlcmd scripting variables. Scripting variables have the following format: $(VARNAME).

Variable names are case insensitive.